# How can I change the character displayed before each Joomla! Menu item?

Tags: joomla, menuitem

Can you help me understand how to remove the characters (-> and >)  that are added to the HTML before each Joomla! 3.4.8 menu item.  ~Thanks[image: ![Menu items in Joomla website]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnnoR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix, I modified the template's responsive.css and style.css files by replacing the li:before rules for the block (aftercontent) that I have the module in - this getting rid of the *chevron* character.

**BEFORE**

```
#block-aftercontent ul li:before {
 content: "\f054";
font-family:fontawesome;
font-weight:bold;
color:#161616;
margin-right:7px;
font-size:0.7em;
}
```

**AFTER**

```
#block-aftercontent ul li:before {
 content: "";
}
```

If you know a more local way of changing the li:before style for the module, I would appreciate your response.  ~Best regards